# Change not in subquery to left outer join in HQL

Tags: java, mysql, left-join, hql

I have the following HQL with me

```
select distinct(ordr) 
from OfOrder ordr, 
SalesChannel sc  
where  
   ordr.status in (:statusList) and 
   ordr.ofOrderId not in (
          select ordrLabel2.ofOrder.ofOrderId 
          from OrderLabel ordrLabel2 
          where 
             ordrLabel2.ofLabel.labelId in ( :ofLabels )
          ) and 
  ordr.orderMain.salesChannel.channelId in (:channelIds)  and 
  ordr.deliveryChannel.deliveryChannelId in (:deliveryChannels) 
order by ordr.deliveryDate asc,   
CASE   
  when ordr.status = 'SU' then 1 
  when ordr.status = 'SU' then 1 
  when ordr.status = 'SU' then 1 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 2 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 2 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 2 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 3 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 4 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 4 
  when ordr.status = 'SH' then 5 
  when ordr.status = 'SH' then 5 
  when ordr.status = 'DD' then 6 
  when ordr.status = 'R' then 7 
  when ordr.status = 'C' then 8 
  ELSE 9999    
END
```

Hibernate generated the following query for the same

```
select distinct oforder0_.`of_order_id`
as of_order1_27_, oforder0_.`assigned_to`
as assigned2_27_, oforder0_.`box_size`
as box_size3_27_, oforder0_.`boxes`
as boxes4_27_, oforder0_.`created_date`
as created_5_27_, oforder0_.`delivery_channel_id`
as deliver25_27_, oforder0_.`delivery_channel_order_id`
as delivery6_27_, oforder0_.`delivery_date`
as delivery7_27_, oforder0_.`delivery_labelled`
as delivery8_27_, oforder0_.`delivery_status`
as delivery9_27_, oforder0_.`description`
as descrip10_27_, oforder0_.`display_name`
as display11_27_, oforder0_.`fulfillment_center_id`
as fulfill26_27_, oforder0_.`kitchen_labelled`
as kitchen12_27_, oforder0_.`message`
as message13_27_, oforder0_.`group_id`
as group_i27_27_, oforder0_.`shipping_address_id`
as shippin28_27_, oforder0_.`order_main_id`
as order_m29_27_, oforder0_.`order_type`
as order_t14_27_, oforder0_.`packing_priority`
as packing15_27_, oforder0_.`quantity`
as quantit16_27_, oforder0_.`requiresShipping`
as require17_27_, oforder0_.`shipping_line_id`
as shippin30_27_, oforder0_.`split_number`
as split_n18_27_, oforder0_.`status`
as status19_27_, oforder0_.`total_price`
as total_p20_27_, oforder0_.`tracking_id`
as trackin21_27_, oforder0_.`updated_date`
as updated22_27_, oforder0_.`vendor_id`
as vendor_23_27_, oforder0_.`vendor_name`
as vendor_24_27_
from `of_order` oforder0_
cross join `sales_channel` saleschann1_
    cross join `order_main` ordermain3_
where oforder0_.`order_main_id`=ordermain3_.`order_main_id`
        and (oforder0_.`status` in ('SU' , 'AC'))
        and (oforder0_.`of_order_id`
        not in  (
select orderlabel2_.`of_order_id`
            from `order_label` orderlabel2_
            where orderlabel2_.`label_id`
            in (29 , 37)
            )
)
and (ordermain3_.`channel_id`
in (1 , 4)
            )
        and (oforder0_.`delivery_channel_id`
in (2 , 5)
            )
order by oforder0_.`delivery_date` asc,
    case
when oforder0_.`status`='SU' then 1
        when oforder0_.`status`='SU' then 1
        when oforder0_.`status`='SU' then 1
        when oforder0_.`status`='AC' then 2
        when oforder0_.`status`='AC' then 2
        when oforder0_.`status`='AC' then 2
        when oforder0_.`status`='AC' then 3
        when oforder0_.`status`='AC' then 4
        when oforder0_.`status`='AC' then 4
        when oforder0_.`status`='SH' then 5
        when oforder0_.`status`='SH' then 5
        when oforder0_.`status`='DD' then 6
        when oforder0_.`status`='R' then 7
        when oforder0_.`status`='C' then 8
        else 9999
end
limit 50, 50;
```

The above query gives me the exact result that I need. But I think join queries will improve the performance. Please correct me if not.
How to do that
I need to change the subquery part to left outer join

**(select ordrLabel2.ofOrder.ofOrderId from OrderLabel ordrLabel2 where ordrLabel2.ofLabel.labelId in ( :ofLabels )**

How to to achieve the same result by outer join.
I need a HQL for the above result with left outer join
Some one please help me to achieve this

Comment: I'd be tempted to start with something simpler

Comment: Sure, Please answer then. I am waiting.
If a better option than left outer join or subquery is also most welcome!!

Comment: One thing, Faseela, have you notice that WHEN clauses at the end of the HQL expression are duplicated (and even triplicated)? It seems strange.

Comment: That "when" are from inside "case" you may notice that in SQLQuery too

Comment: `ordr.orderMain.salesChannel.channelId` makes no sense.  The longest string that MySQL can handle is `dbname.tablename.colname`; you have 4 things strung together???

Comment: salesChannelid is a foreign key reference from salesChannel table to orderManin table. In hibernate it is possible in either way. we can either directly use ordr.orderMain.salesChannelId or ordr.orderMain.salesChannel.channelId . This is a HQL not mysql query.
Mysql query is given below to that.

also this query gives the exact result that need. only thing is need to change subquery to left outer join

Comment: The part you want to "optimize" is a constant list (it depends only on the `ofLabels` parameter). MySQL should notice it and evaluate it only once, which gives optimal performance.

Comment: Sorry @Olivier I didn't get that. how to make it constant list.

Comment: Your query is fine as it is. There is no reason to change it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need performance, don't rely on hql/sql conversion, go for native queries and don't select all fields, but only one you really need.

Another strategy is to build a view on your data ( investigate on materialized view too ) and then hql / sql on that, in this way you can have a simpler data model, good performance and fine control on how to handle data on your database.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your suggestion, but I need an exact hql query for the same which using outer join instead of subquery

Comment: then what if is better to write in sql and then use it as native query instead to use hql ?

Comment: I'm using this in a hibernate environment. and enabling inverse search with label  in already running application. I'm thinking is to go with minimal changes

Comment: hibernate let you use native query, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/query_native.html as example

Comment: tying to add an extra feature with minimal changes. the application is already using hql

Answer (score 1):

if it makes sense to do left join instead of cross join, you can chnage your query to this , also for your order by , you can simplify it as well:

```
select distinct(ordr) 
from OfOrder as ordr left join ordr.SalesChannel as sc  
where  
   ordr.status in (:statusList) 
   and ordr.ofOrderId not in (
          select ordrLabel2.ofOrder.ofOrderId 
          from OrderLabel ordrLabel2 
          where ordrLabel2.ofLabel.labelId in (:ofLabels )
          ) 
    and ordr.orderMain.salesChannel.channelId in (:channelIds)
    and ordr.deliveryChannel.deliveryChannelId in (:deliveryChannels) 
order by ordr.deliveryDate asc,   
CASE   
  when ordr.status = 'SU' then 1 
  when ordr.status = 'AC' then 2 
  when ordr.status = 'SH' then 3
  when ordr.status = 'DD' then 4 
  when ordr.status = 'R' then 5
  when ordr.status = 'C' then 6 
  ELSE 9999    
END
```

Comment: thank for your answer, the thing that I need is to keep the SalesChannel join is as it as. and improving the sub query part,
that is all other join is as it as but add a left outer join for orderLabel table and remove the subquery part

Comment: @Faseela there is pretty much nothing to improve for subquery